# LMER model failed to converge due to repeating identical observations by ID, what now

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a mixed fixed and random effects model:

```
m1=lmer(pollution~  GDP2018 + vehicle_percapita + HH_SolidFuel + interruption  + obs_seasons  + interruption:HH_SolidFuel  + 
       days +interruption:days +   interruption:GDP2018 + interruption:obs_seasons + interruption:vehicle_percapita + ( 1 + days | SiteName), data=new8, REML = FALSE)
```

I've figured out why i'm getting the "model failed to converge" error ... for each SiteName (my random term) I have repeating observations for the other predictors ie

SiteName      Days          GDP

Uganda          1            10,000

Uganda          2            10,000

Uganda          3            10,000
...... for up to 2000 observations by Site (GDP would differ by site but not within site)

so when I remove the random effect "Site Name" my model runs smooth but I need to account for this important random effect based on intuition/literature/ etc.

my question is how can i include SiteName (evaluate/ control for the random effect of site on pollution) in a model, knowing that by site there are many identical responses for certain variables over the whole time period.

Comment: Which variables vary within site ? Please can you include the output of `head(mydata)`

Comment: The only variable which varies is the outcome (average pm2.5) and "days" the time variable which indicates day of observation. My output for head is too long, sorry!